# React Highcharts error

Tags: reactjs, axios, highcharts, tradier

Looking for some help with the react wrapper for highcharts it seems to be throwing this error every-time I go to start the dev server for my application.

[Error message Highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHrBD.png)

With that Said I am sure that It is an issue with my code and not the Highcharts react wrapper. I am looking for some help to remedy this error. Thank you.

I am using another node wrapper for the Tradier API for market data and want to compare multiple tickers historically like the chart that is provided in Highchart's Demo. [(Found here)](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare/dark-unica)

I Know I need to iterate through the returned JSON from Tradier- which
returns an array of objects for a particular ticker symbol.

```
{ day: 
[ { date: '2017-01-03',
   open: 115.8,
   high: 116.33,
   low: 114.76,
   close: 116.15,
   volume: 28781865 }... 
]
```

I have Gone ahead and uploaded the app to a github repository. The code for the Highstock component I am trying to add in react is below, along with the github links for the used packages.

```
import React from 'react'

import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import Tradier from 'tradier-client';

class HighchartSector extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props)
    this.state = {
      store: [],
      openPrice: []
    }
  }
    componentDidMount() {
      const tradier = new Tradier('7svYXqoAjts9fGptLU7mtKo4Z4Oa', 'sandbox');

      tradier.historical('LADR')
      .then(history => history.day.map( result =>(
        {
        open: `${result.open}`,
       })))
       .then(newData => this.setState({openPrice: newData, store: newData}))
       .catch(error => alert(error))

    }
    render() {

      const { openPrice } = this.state;

      const options = {
        title: {
          text: 'My stock chart'
        },
        series: [{
          data: openPrice
        }]
      }

    return (

      <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      constructorType={'stockChart'}
      options={options}
    />

    )
  }
}


export default HighchartSector
```

My Git Repo: [HERE](https://github.com/whundahl/rhino-react/blob/master/src/pages/Dashboard/sectorTemplate/DashboardCrypto/TradeChart/index.js)

Tradier vporta wrapper: [HERE](https://github.com/vporta/tradier-client)

Highcharts-Official React Wrapper: [HERE](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react)

Comment: Please describe what do you have problem with.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment I am trying to take the response JSON iterate through the "days" array and return the open price for the highstocks chart. TRhe JSON needs to be parsed as well to do this, but I am wondering if maybe the data call to the API should be made in a different file and then imported into the react component with the highstock.

Comment: Thank you for the help, just looking to load the highcharts correctly In my app so I can work with the options for each chart